# Could not find Connection Setting with name botconnection - Teams Bot SSO

Tags: botframework, teams-toolkit

**setup**:
I have a bot registered in developer portal and created a app by teams tool kit.To add SSO for my bot i have created a azure bot with multi-tenant and create new app.Under bot configuration oauth connection setting create a service provider with azure ad v2.0 name botConnection,client Id  & secret of my app already created by tool kit in token exchange url api://botid-clientidofapp then tenant is common and scope is set to User.Read,openId,email.
**problem**:
when i try to debug the bot while the oauth begin dialog throws **"Could not find Connection Setting with name botconnection"**. i have set webapplicationinfo in manifest with client id of the app.
any one can help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but did you update your code accordingly? You can check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned%2Caadv2%2Ccsharp which teaches you how to add authentication for Azure bot.

Also, Teams Toolkit supports adding sso for the scaffolded project. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/add-single-sign-on?tabs=typescript%2F%3Ffrom%3Dteamstoolkit to see if it can help in your case.

Comment: thanks for your response,but already i experimented these doc's first one using bot service still rise same issue. so i tried second way using teamsBotprompt but I'm trying to sso for notification bot each time try to prompt begindialog it runs continuously  it status waiting not login page redirects